# How to patch on Windows?

Tags: windows, patch

Given a (source) patch file, what's the easiest way to apply this patch on the source files under Windows?

A GUI tool where I can visually compare the unchanged-changed source lines would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Patch for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Note that this patch doesn't play nice with Vista's UAC. Try Git-for-windows's patch.exe instead, that comes with a manifest that solves the issue.

Comment: @Macke is right ! See my answer for a how-to with GIT !

Comment: Actually what @Macke is referring to is that in Windows an exec called `patch.exe` requires Admin access and if UAE is set to on, it pauses and prompts the user.  Now, the Git version of `patch.exe` embeds a manifest that prevents the UAE elevation need.

This happens to be a old legacy thing with windows in that any `exe` that has `install`, `patch`, `setup` in the name will force a UAE elevation UNLESS the manifest is supplied.  The patch gets applied: [patch patch](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/blob/900744becd072f687029b0f830ab6fe95cf533d6/patch/msys2-patch-manifest.patch)

Answer (score 20):

A good way to apply a patch file under Windows OS is using Git.
As I understood, Git is a version control solution like SVN.

**Here is a guideline to apply a patch :**

- First of all, download the latest release of the Windows Git Edition here :
  [GIT](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=official%20Git)
- With the cmd prompt, change directory to the patch file and files to patch
- Now you can use the following command line :

> ```
> git apply --ignore-space-change --ignore-whitespace --whitespace=nowarn file.patch
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Not that since Git 2.3.3 (March 2015), you can use `git apply --unsafe-paths` to use git apply outside a git repo.

See [commit 5244a31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5244a31039dbb3fe0d544fc56100d0ccbc653131) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster)

"`git apply`" was not very careful about reading from, removing, updating and creating paths outside the working tree (under `--index`/`--cached`) or the current directory (when used as a replacement for GNU patch).

The documentation now includes:

```
--unsafe-paths:
```

> By default, a patch that affects outside the working area (either a Git controlled working tree, or the current working directory when "`git apply`" is used as a replacement of GNU patch) is rejected as a mistake (or a mischief).
>
> When `git apply` is used as a "better GNU patch", the user can pass the `--unsafe-paths` option to override this safety check.
>   This option has no effect when `--index` or `--cached` is in use.

So if you have [git installed](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases), `git apply` could help, even outside of any git repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [patch](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/patch) it via Cocolatey:

```
choco install patch
```

Answer (score -2):

WinMerge is awesome.

http://winmerge.org/

Comment: Winmerge is great at creating patches, but not at applying them. The OP asked about how to apply it.  It would be a fabulous new feature if WinMerge could apply a patch and then show the changes that were made.

Comment: **Found in the WinMerge Help**
patches cannot be applied using WinMerge. However, you can apply patches using the patch tool from the GnuWin32 project, because WinMerge produces patch files that are compatible with GNU/diffutils. Also, see the preceding question.

Comment: I was looking for this. Thanks. I did googling "how to make patches" this page come up top, so..