# Enabling Multisampling in wxPython OpenGL Context

Tags: python, opengl, wxpython, pyopengl, multisampling

I'm trying to enable multisampling in an OpenGL program I'm writing.  The application will require a substantial amount of GUI, so I am using wxPython (with which I am less familiar) instead of PyGame (SDL).

I really need hardware multisampling for the main GLCanvas.  I am aware that this is borderline possible in the C++ version of wx, e.g., [How to enable multisampling for a wxWidgets OpenGL program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560/how-to-enable-multisampling-for-a-wxwidgets-opengl-program).  However, I attempted something similar, but it didn't work for wx**Python**.

So, what I want to know is, is multisampling even possible with wxPython?

Ideas I've already thought of:

- Use a PyGame context inside a wx.Frame instead.  Use SDL's hardware multisampling.  No idea if this would actually work.  IIRC, resizing SDL OpenGL contexts destroys their contents, which would be somewhat of a problem with this application.  Although . . . I guess it might be workable.
- Use a FBO with a higher resolution to render, and then downsample with multisampling.  This . . . works, sorta.  But supersampling is much slower than multisampling, and the technique doesn't work very well for things like GL_LINE.  I have already tried this solution.
- Use a FBO with a multisampling render target.  This would involve a lot of changes, and would limit cross-system portability.
- Ideally: use wxPython's built-in support, if it exists.

Comment: The third option is 100% working one.I don't know the internals of Python wrapper but for example in Java wrapper like LWJGL you can set amount of multi-sampling when creating the display context.Are you sure there is not something like that in wxPython ?

Comment: No, which is why I'm asking.  I did however give it a fairly thorough check, and I didn't see anything wxPython offers when making the window.